# Receive an image on the iPhone (TCP Client)

Tags: iphone, ios, image, tcp, client-server

I'm programming a client on the iPhone. I want to send some strings, and receive an image from the server.

I found this tutorial (http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551), it has been very useful. It works if I want to receive strings, but now I want to receive an image, and I can't make it work.

This is my code when the iPhone receives data. It's a mix made with the tutorial and this answer from JeremyP (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613218):

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {

switch(eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
        if (data == nil) {
            data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }
        uint8_t buf[102400];
        unsigned int len = 0;
        len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:102400];

        if(len) {    
            [data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];

            // Recibir img
    uint8_t size;  // Let's make sure size is an explicit width.

            NSInteger totalBytesRead = 0;
            NSInteger bytesRead = [iStream read: &size maxLength: sizeof size];
            while (bytesRead > 0 && totalBytesRead + bytesRead < sizeof size) {
                totalBytesRead+= bytesRead;
                bytesRead = [iStream read: &size + totalBytesRead maxLength: (sizeof size) - totalBytesRead];
            }
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
            else {
                // read failure, report error and bail
            }
            if (totalBytesRead < sizeof size) {
                // connection closed before we got the whole size, report and bail
            }
            size = ntohl(size);  // assume wire protocol uses network byte ordering

            NSMutableData* buffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: size];
            totalBytesRead = 0;
            bytesRead = [iStream read: [buffer mutableBytes] maxLength: size];
            while (bytesRead > 0 && totalBytesRead + bytesRead < size) {
                totalBytesRead+= bytesRead;
                bytesRead = [iStream read: [buffer mutableBytes] + totalBytesRead maxLength: size - totalBytesRead];
            }
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
            else {
                // read failure, report error and bail (not forgetting to release buffer)
            }
            if (totalBytesRead < size) {
                // connection closed before we got the whole image, report and bail (not forgetting to release buffer)
            }
            else {
                [buffer setLength: size];
            }

            imgResultado.image = [UIImage imageWithData: buffer];
            [buffer release];
            [data release];        
            data = nil;

        } 
        else {
            NSLog(@"No data.");
        }


    } break;
}}
```

It doesn't work... could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I made it work this way, but I'm no sure if there's a better way.

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
switch(eventCode) {
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    {
        uint32_t max_size = 1000000;  // Max size of the received imaged.
        NSMutableData* buffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: max_size];
        NSInteger totalBytesRead = 0;
        NSInteger bytesRead = [(NSInputStream *)stream read: [buffer mutableBytes] maxLength: max_size];
        if (bytesRead != 0) {
            while (bytesRead > 0 && totalBytesRead + bytesRead < max_size) {
                totalBytesRead+= bytesRead;
                bytesRead = [(NSInputStream *)stream read: [buffer mutableBytes] + totalBytesRead maxLength: max_size - totalBytesRead];
            }
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
            else {
                // read failure, report error and bail (not forgetting to release buffer)
            }
            [buffer setLength: totalBytesRead];
            imgResultado.image = [UIImage imageWithData: buffer];
            [buffer release];
        }
    } break;
}}
```

With this method, the received image must be smaller than max_size.
If you know a better way to do this, please let me know! ;)

Comment: This means that your server is not transmitting a size integer at the beginning of the stream like your previous code was expecting. That is why your previous code did not work, because you effectively dropped the first 4 bytes if the image data.

Comment: so, with this code, you can receive image upto 1000000 bytes.  That is almost 1MB? (your original code only had about 100k?) Just try to confirm...

Comment: user523234 yes, the client can receive images upto 1000000 bytes. Claireware, that could be a good explanation, I think that you're right. That way is safer than my answer, but if I want to use it, I'll need to modify the server.

Comment: Good for you.  I encountered a 128K limitation per stream when I did something similar to this.  So I had to break up my image to < 128K chunk.  It would be interesting to see how your stream is sent out.

Comment: I've tried to send an image  of 300k, and there's no problem. The server is in visual basic, I convert the image to a bytes array, and then I use the write function on the stream: stream.Write(byteArray,0,byteArray.length)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is download an image from the server to display, take a look at this:

https://github.com/michaelkamprath/iPhoneMK/tree/master/Views/MKNetworkImageView

There are a lot of built in functions to the iOS that will handle image downloading for you. That is, if you can encapsulate the entities you want to download as separate URLs (e.g., a web server).

If, however, you are trying to send and receive data across the same TCP connection, I would strongly advise that you change to a more RESTful approach. Partly because it is easier to implement from the client side, partly because you don't have to worry (as much) about the underlying TCP connection.

Comment: The image isn't in the web. The server generates an image with the data sent by the client, and then sends the image through the TCP connection. I have to program the TCP client in the iPhone to receive and show that image.

Comment: Do you know what data format the server is returning? imageWithData: only works with JPG, PNG, etc. If your server is returning raw pixel data, then that won't work.