# UIImage not received correctly from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, inputstream

I am kind of new to objective-c so please help. i am receiving the image but not completely here is my code.
I am sure that the problems is here and not on the server side, but if you need me to post the code of the server side then ill do that.

```
       uint8_t buf[3000000];
       int len = 0;
       len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:3000000];
       UIImage* fooo ;
       NSMutableData *dataa=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
       do{
       len = [inputStream read:buf maxLength:3000000];
           if(len>0) current+=len;
       }
       while (len>-1);
       [dataa appendBytes: (const void *)buf length:current];
       fooo = [[UIImage alloc]  initWithData:dataa];
   [inputStream close];
   [outputStream close];
```

server side

```
 String FilePath=xxxxx.jpeg";
 System.out.println (FilePath);
  File file1=new     
   File(xxxxxx\\38.jpeg");
   long v=file1.length();
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)file1.length()]; 
FileInputStream fis = new     
    FileInputStream(FilePath);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new    
    BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    os = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();//outpustream
    System.out.println("Sending...");
    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length); 
    System.out.println("Sent");
    os.flush();
```

Comment: It will be very easy if you get url from server side for an image and get image like this... `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];`

Comment: The server is a java server and i am sending and receiving using sockets

Comment: This can work with any server... But as socket is your requirements you are doing right... In that case may be some packet yet not received...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447815/receive-an-image-on-the-iphone-tcp-client

Comment: And if the image size is greater then your allocated buffer then you will be missing some thing >

Comment: Yes that is the problem but how can i solve it. The image size wont exceed the max length. its always smaller

Comment: One thing you create buffer with large enough size, it always being a problem with streaming. You can call first to get size of buffer and than actual loading...

Comment: when i send from the client to the server i am also not sending the size and allocating the buffer on the server in the same way, and its working.

Comment: In server you are creating buffer with the length of file and that's fine. But in client code you are creating buffer of constant size. It should be also some thing byte size which are coming from server...?

Comment: Got your problem, every time when stream comes you creating a new data and try to append.. but actually you are not appending all data to one data object

Comment: do you think stream will come in one whole chunk... I think not... So allocate image here is also not good. when stream is finished you should use that to initialize image object.

Comment: yes i agree with you sir. but with the code i just edited (client), when i print current, it is printing the actual file size of the image sent from the server, but after it reaches this size, nothing happens(it freezes).

Comment: can u please see my answer and change your code like that...

Comment: And i am sorry if i am not being able to explain very well, but english is not my main language and i am new to networking

Answer (score 0):

Every time when stream comes you creating a new data and try to append.. but actually you are not appending all data to one data object you are doing this way `NSMutableData *dataa=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0]`

I will prefer have an instance variable and do like this

```
 if(!_data) {
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
 }
```

Whole code should be like this, code is from apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-BCIJHAGD)

```
switch(eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            if(!_data) {
                _data = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            }
            uint8_t buf[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:1024];
            if(len) {
                [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
                // bytesRead is an instance variable of type NSNumber .
                [bytesRead setIntValue:[bytesRead intValue]+len];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"no buffer!");
            }
            break;
        }
```

You should handle stream events. Stream will not bring data in one big chunk, so that's why we appending data here. Delegate method will be called with an event and you can set check on event. 
When you got this event `NSStreamEventEndEncountered` close your `stream` object and create `uiimage` `object`

```
switch(NSStreamEventEndEncountered){
   [stream close];
   [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   [stream release];
   stream = nil; // stream is ivar, so reinit it

  if (_data!=nil)
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:_data];
}
```